# How to differentiate two users in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

If I have the two users in the Microsoft Teams with the same name like "John Smith" .we can add two users with same name but different email id. Now in the API to get the channel messages the response will be its part of response like:

```
"mentions": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "mentionText": "John Smith",
                "mentioned": {
                    "application": null,
                    "device": null,
                    "conversation": null,
                    "user": {
                        "id": "5fc21b65-9c9b-4b73-ac2c-d5dafe1cf08f",
                        "displayName": "John Smith",
                        "userIdentityType": "aadUser"
                    }
                }
            }
```

but in this response I am not getting the email id to verify from which user we got the response if I have two John smith.How to tackle this situation

Answer (score 0):

@NDD Once you get the id of the user you could use that id to make an api call to fetch [users profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-standard-users-request). There you could get the email id of the user.